# Firebase onDataChange gives weird result (in java)

Tags: java, firebase, corrupt

supposing I have two clients A and B
They each write a message to firebase within a few milliseconds of each other.
A writes "AAA", B writes "BBB".
Lets assume A's message gets there first though.

Then for client A:

onDataChange()

1. "Some message"
2. "Another message"
3. "AAA"

onDataChange()

1. "Some message"
2. "Another message"
3. "AAA"          <--- correct as "AAA" was first
4. "BBB"

But for client B:

onDataChange()

1. "Some message"
2. "Another message"
3. "BBB"

onDataChange()

1. "Some message"
2. "Another message"
3. "AAA"          <--- correct as "AAA" was first
4. "BBB"

So you can see the first time each client gets data back, they receive different data.
The correct data is sent just after, but still, this first received data is going to corrupt my programs workings at some point.
Is there anyway to resolve this?

Thanks for any help.

---

Ok, I got it working, but now I'm stuck again

I was using push() on the Firebase reference before, so that it gave something like.. -Qj73473429 and then my data (key->value) was under it. This was good, as it ordered in the order it was written.

But now using Transaction, I have to use the MutableData object, instead of the Firebase one. And I can't use push on this, so the data (key->value) was then ordered alphabetically by the key, which is no good for me.

Do you know how I can fix this, I tried applying md.setPriority(1), but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is annoying, its just one problem after another, arghh.

Please help if you can

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing what you've tried so far? That will provide a great starting point for fixing you up! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about real-time bits flying through cyberspace, there is no guarantee what order messages will arrive at the client. Instead of attempting to guarantee the impossible, Firebase explicitly tells you what the previous child of each new record is.

From the example under [reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html). Note the `prevChildName` string:

```
Firebase usersRef = new Firebase("https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/");
usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
    String userName = snapshot.getName();
    System.out.println(userName + " was added after " + previousChildName);
  },

  /* other methods ... */
});
```

This is illuminated in the paragraph just above, although it's not directly stated that it also applies to child_added events:

> Events that are triggered on your client do not always correspond
>   exactly with the write operations that were performed on other
>   clients. For example, if two other clients were to set the same piece
>   of data at approximately the same time, there is no guarantee that two
>   events will be triggered on your local client. Depending on the
>   timing, those two changes could be aggregated into a single local
>   event. Regardless, eventually all clients will have a consistent view
>   of the data, even if the events triggered in the process may differ
>   from client-to-client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...   you are right, the clients do get the right data sent to them afterwards. I have found this though...   https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html .... It seems to explain my problem exactly, I think. So the solution is transactions.  I will let you know if I get stuck. Thanks.